# Use cases for ServletContextAttributeListener

Tags: java, tomcat, listener

I understand that we can use `javax.servlet.ServletContextAttributeListener` if we want to know that an attribute in a web app context has been added, removed or replaced. But what are some practical use cases for this listener? (I googled around for a while, but could not find any practical examples for this listener.)

Answer (score 0):

The `javax.servlet.ServletContext` interface represents a view of the Web Application to filters and servlets that belongs to. Through the `ServletContext` interface, a Servlet or Filter can access raw input streams of Web Application resources, mechanism for logging information, virtual directory translation, and an application scope for binding objects.

The application scope for binding objects consists common objects for Servlets and Filters. Those objects should be consistent with some rules, so any change should be checked. And this is a one of the cases where `javax.servlet.ServletContextAttributeListener` can be used.